# No Internet Connection after macchanger

Tags: 16.04, wireless, mac

i ran the following :

```
sudo ifconfig wlp68s0b1 down
sudo macchanger -r wlp68s0b1
sudo ifconfig wlp68s0b1 up
```

Then found no internet connection , in order to restore the connection i ran :

```
service network-manager restart
```

but that gives me the old MAC again

my hardware is : Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

any ideas ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try `dhclient` after `sudo ifconfig wlp68s0b1 up`.